# RewriteRule the website except files

Tags: http, mod-rewrite

Currently I have a RewriteRule in httpd.conf which leads example-domain.org to example-domain2.org:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ http://www.example-domain2.org [R,L]
```

But I would like to not redirect file requests under www.example-domain.org/downloads/*

Is it possible somehow? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule downloads/ - [L]  # do not rewrite downloads/
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example-domain2.org [R,L]  #redirect anything else
```